# How to get the value other property within annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I want to get the value of other property in scope of annotation.

*example*

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetBatchCount", action = NAMESPACE + getOperationName())
```

`getOperationName()` should return value set to `operationName`.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JLS [§9.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) (emphasis is mine) the following are allowed combinations in *element-value* pairs:

> The type of V is assignment compatible (§5.2) with T, and furthermore:
>
> - If T is a primitive type or String, and V is a **constant expression** (§15.28).
> - V is not null.
> - If T is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a **class literal** (§15.8.2).
> - If T is an enum type, and V is an **enum constant**.

So, as you can see, value can be only a constant of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a method inside the parameter block of an annotation.